# Meaning of sentence from "A Tale of Two Cities"

Tags: meaning, charles-dickens, a-tale-of-two-cities

> Reins and whip and coachman and guard, however, in combination, **had read that article of war which forbade a purpose** otherwise strongly in favour of the argument, that some brute animals are endued with Reason; and the team had capitulated and returned to their duty.

What does this mean? (Bolding my own.)

Answer (score 4):

The [Articles of War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articles_of_War) are (and were, since before Dickens's time) the official regulations defining the scope of military  and naval  discipline in the UK.  They were  read on ceremonial occasions and on occasions when a commander felt that discipline was lax.  To "read the Articles of War" was the martial equivalent of "reading the riot act".

In this passage, Dickens says that the coachman and guard brought the   rebellious horses back into a state of obedience.